# Importing a Native Bridge module into javascript in React Native

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

I'd like to import my module written natively (java, Android) into my React Native sources, in JS.

I have my dependencies loaded into: `android/app/libs/dependencies.jar`
I have created my module into `android/app/src/main/java/com/rctcognito/`:

Beside some source files, I have the module and the package.

The module is implementing the following class:
`public class Cognito extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule`

And here is the package class:

```
package com.rctcognito;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RCTCognitoPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules( ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
            modules.add(new Cognito(reactContext));
            return modules;
    }
}
```

I, then, updated `MainApplication.java` by adding the new package:
`import com.rctcognito.RCTCognitoPackage;`
And adding it in the List: 
`new RCTCognitoPackage(),`

Considering to the official doc of React-Native, I should be able to load it like this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.Cognito;
import Cognito from './Cognito';
```

But my app is not able to load `./Cognito`. Would you have any idea what I might be doing wrong please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works.

All native modules are exposed via `NativeModules` submodule provided by React Native.

This is correct usage.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { Cognito } = NativeModules;
```

Go ahead and do simple `console.log(NativeModules)` to see, what's exposed from native codebase.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

Create a file Cognite.js

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.Cognite;
```

And then import it where you needed by:

```
import Cognite from './Cognite';
```

Another way is to just import directly:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { Cognito } = NativeModules;
```

You can check out React Native Bridge which works in both iOS and Android -> https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/react-native-bridge-for-ios-and-android-43feb9712fcb